# Searching __builtin_popcount in man

Tags: gcc

Wanted to search for the man pages of the `__builtin_popcount` function.

I typed in `$ man __builtin` and hit `TAB`, which turned it into `$man ./__builtin/`. Why did this happen ?

Then, I typed in *_popcount* and hit `return`, but couldn't find the man page. How do I then search for the `__builtin_*` functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apropos` command to search for keywords within the installed man pages:

```
$ apropos builtin
bash-builtins (7)    - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
builtins (7)         - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
$ apropos __builtin_popcount
__builtin_popcount: nothing appropriate.
$
```

Doesn't look like there is a man page for this GCC extension.  I think you'll have to use [the online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) instead:

> — Built-in Function: int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
>
> Returns the number of 1-bits in x.

Answer (score 0):

Because pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> invokes autocomplete, which spotted a matching filename/directory name.

Does `man builtin` achieve what you want ?

```
man builtin

BASH_BUILTINS(1)            General Commands Manual           
...
BASH_BUILTINS(1)
...
BASH BUILTIN COMMANDS
   Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this section
   as accepting options preceded by - accepts -- to signify the end of the
   options.   The  :, true, false, and test builtins do not accept options
   and do not treat -- specially.  The exit, logout, break, continue, let,
```

Comment: This is about a function provided by the GCC compiler. Also notice the peculiar way in which __builtin was expanded...

Answer (score 0):

It's in the gcc manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/. There's no manpages for it AFAIK.